# Why am I missing a module in python that should be installed when I do system calls from java?

Tags: java, python, command-line, argparse

I am trying to run a python script inside a java program using:

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
String s = "python -c \"import argparse; print argparse\""
executor.execute(s);
```

but getting the error message:

`"import argparse ImportError: No module named argparse\n"`

This python module is automatically installed in python 2.7+

The command works fine when I just run it from the terminal:

```
$python -v
Python 2.7.1
$python -c "import argparse; print argparse"
<module 'argparse' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.pyc'>
```

Why doesn't it work from the java program? Is `DefaultExecutor` using a different machine?

Comment: What verison of python is Java running? Is it a different version, or other env vars are set differently?

Comment: how would I check that?

Comment: Okay problem solved, the problem was me trying to run the java program as root user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having your DefaultExecutor run `"python -v"` and see if it gives you any hints. Maybe Java is using the wrong version of python for some reason to be discovered.

Or try running:

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
String s = "python  \"import sys; print sys.executable\""
executor.execute(s);
```

That might allow you to see which version of python Java is using.

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: yeah, the problem was me trying to run the java program as root user. When I switched to another user, it worked fine.